# How to count the number of unique strings in each element of a list

Tags: r, string, list, for-loop, unique

I have a list with a number of strings. I would like to count the number of unique strings in each element of the list. For example:

My list called test looks like:

```
test <- list(
  c("X", "Y", "Z", "X"),
  c("W", "X", "X"), 
  c("Z", "W",  "Y", "X", "Z", "Z")
)
```

I would like an output that can tell me something like:

```
[[1]] 3
[[2]] 2
[[3]] 4
```

I am able to count this for each individual element easily by using the following code:

```
length(unique(test[[1]]))
```

However, I am unsure how to automate this for a large list. I have tried to make a for loop as shown below, but I get the following error:

```
test_length <- for(i in test){length(unique(test[[i]]))}
```

Error in test[[i]] : no such index at level 1

Comment: `sapply(test, function(element) {length(unique(element))})`  just try this.

Comment: You can use a for loop such as `test_length <- rep(NA_integer_,length(test))
  for(i in 1:length(test)){
    test_length[i] <- length(unique(test[[i]]))
  }`

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly :)

Comment: Another condensed option: `lengths(Map(unique, test))`

Comment: Kerry Jackson, your suggestion gave the following error: Error: unexpected 'for' in "test_length <- rep(NA_integer_,length(test)) for"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lapply` instead

```
> lapply(test, function(x) length(unique(x)))

[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
   map_int(n_distinct)
#[1] 3 2 4
```